# Getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error when music stops playing

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP App I have a `ListView` with all songs displayed in the `Music Library` folder.   When you click on a song it will play it and move to the next song when the first one stops.  All this works great, however when the last song plays and reaches the end I get this error

```
System.ArgumentException
HResult=0x80070057
Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
Source=Windows
StackTrace:
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.Selector.put_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
```

This is the code I have:

```
private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Stop();

        if (AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex <= AudioFilesLV.Items.Count)
        {
            AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex += 1;
            var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
                mediaElement.Play();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void mediaItemList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void objMediaPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

The App crashes at this line:

```
 AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex += 1;
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.  I think it is looking for the next song but there isn't one.  So I need to tell the app to stop after the last song plays, but don't know how to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int LastPlayedIndex;
        LastPlayedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex;
            AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = 1;
            var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex < AudioFilesLV.Items.Count && AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex != LastPlayedIndex)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
                mediaElement.Play();
            }

        else
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex += 1` is more than `AudioFilesLV.Items.Count` ? Condition above is "<=", so index may be out of range.
Maybe needeed another check, if .SelectedIndex is last in list, and do not increment value in this case?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.  I have tried not to increment the value but it still does not stop playing after the last song in my listview, it just keeps repeating the last song.

Comment: You can try change condition `AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex <= AudioFilesLV.Items.Count` to `AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex < AudioFilesLV.Items.Count`, so if SelectedIndex == Items.Count - else condition with `mediaElement.Stop();` should execute.

Comment: Or another crazy idea - you can surrond faulty code with try-catch block to catch this exception and do something :-)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (updated my question) but still repeating the the last list view song

Comment: Ok. What about to create somewhere a variable, like `int LastPlayedIndex`?
When you call `mediaElement.Play();`, you can set `LastPlayedIndex = SelectedIndex`, and then in the beginning check like this:
`if (AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex < AudioFilesLV.Items.Count && AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex != LastPlayedIndex)` ?

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.  I have updated my question with the working code